# data sample methods in LightGBM

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

### My problem

the usage of all the parameters and how they interact (or should be used) with one another is not very clear to me.

### What I know

As far as I understand, there are 3 algorithms in LightGBM:

- GBDT, the default one, that uses boosting
- DART that is a boosting algorithm with dropouts
- Random Forest, that does not use boosting (well it does, but only on one iteration)

and there are two data sampling strategies:

- Bagging, used for ensemble learning. It's the default value but the value of associated parameters (e.g., bagging_freq) make bagging deactivated.
- GOSS which selects more data that contributes the most to the error gradient (with the idea that we will need to train more on data that is far from the baseline), and less on "weak" data points (those which contribute less to the error gradient).

### Questions

So my questions are the following:

- Why aren't Bagging and GOSS compatible? They don't seem to impact the same thing.
- The main innovation of LightGBM seems to be GOSS, but it is not the default choice, what were the motivations for this?
- Finally, we have the ability to pass `boosting_type=goss` as argument. What happens when we do that? Will the algorithm be *GBDT* with just the data sample strategy being goss?

Thank you very much for your time.

Have a great day.